# Azure IOT Central - ClientError('Unexpected failure') caused by ServiceError('HTTP operation returned: 403 TooManyDevicesError

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-central

We tried leveraging the IoT Central’s File Upload functionality but getting 403 for some file uploads irrespective of the IoTC & Storage account instance.

For the development purpose, we are using Standard 1 tier  and a general Purpose v2 RA-GRS storage account

We are leveraging the python script generating telemetry available on https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/async-hub-scenarios/provision_symmetric_key_group.py
This generates 5 messages in bulk.

We have incorporated the functionality and sample listed on the link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-python-file-upload

The file upload and telemetry initially works fine but when we increate the messages to 10, it starts throwing error some file uploads with the following details - "ClientError('Unexpected failure') caused by ServiceError('HTTP operation returned: 403 TooManyDevicesError(Error: Forbidden)')"

Trying to identify what is the problem, and we did try it with different blob storage and IoT C instances configured so able to eliminate the fact that this is not a Instance related issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

have a look at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling#other-limits

The File uploads limit for underlying IoT Hub of the IoT Central App is 10 concurrent file uploads per device.

Comment: you should received an errorCode=403006 with underlying error message="Number of active file upload requests exceeded limit"